# grep to extract a substring from a huge string

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, html

I am extracting certain information from a website using `curl` command. I need to extract a certain subsection of the string using grep command. For example, using curl command I am getting the HTML page and storing in a variable as below.

```
page="$(curl http://www.somewebsite.com)"
```

My extracted HTML page is as below.

```
<html>
<body>
--------
--------
--------
<div class="section" id="id1" style="display:block">
<div class="header">
      <h2>Sub heading here
      </h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
<ol class="class1" id="id1">
<li class="">
<span class="jellybean">
</div>
----------
----------
</html>
```

Now, I need to extract the subsection of the entire div with **id="id1"**. I tried the below command.

```
output="$(curl http:/somesite.com | grep "id="id1")"
```

It just gets me the 2 lines where I have id=id1. I need to extract the entire contents between the  and  tag.

Comment: Careful: you're going to make [the unholy child weep the blood of virgins!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2105514).

Comment: I found w3m command to scrap out HTML contents in a page. Not explored it completely. But seems interesting. Will update the answer if I found something useful.

Comment: @JosephR. the sample above is not valid XML.

Answer (score 2):

If the file were correct xml, you could use an xml parsing tool.

Otherwise, if there were no other (nested) `div` section inside that section, you could have done:

```
pcregrep -Mo '(?s)<div[^>]*id="id1".*?</div>' the-file.html
```

Here, you could try something like:

```
awk -vRS='<' '
  inside || /^div[^>]*id="id1"/ {
    inside = 1
    if (/^div/)
      n++
    else if (/^\/div>/ && !--n) {
      $0="/div>\n"
      inside=0
    }
    printf "<%s", $0
  }' the-file.html
```